# page background color or image is positioning under header

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a React project and this is how its index-page:
[image]

inside div, I have side bar and its main css:

```
.side-nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 100;
  width: calc(3.5vw + 3.5vh);
```

this is how sidebar,navbar and main page stacked.

```
const BaseLayout: React.FC<BaseLayoutProps> = (props) => {
  const { className, user, navClass = "with-bg", loading, children } = props;
  return (
    // display:flex will keep sideBar and main, side by side
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <SideBar />
      <Header className={navClass} user={user} loading={loading} />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

this is main div for Header

```css
 .port-navbar.port-default {
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 15;
  height: calc(3.5vw + 3.5vh);
}
```

and this is the main div for index-page:

```css
     background-color: green;
```

there is another component under header. I want that component should be under header. In the current structure, I do not understand why index-page does not start right after the header.

Also, I do not understand why I have extra space on the right side of header.

Comment: whats happend if you add the propertie width, may with 100vH? Should the top nav 100% in width or should the sidenav at the right or beside the topnav? Depend on your needs, try to play with the "display" propertie too

Answer (score 0):

first of all `side-nav` is not the class name of the header so the styles will not perform on it.

second, you need to use this for the Header component:

```css
position: absolute;
```

if that didn't work please show some more details and a snippet.